# How does Songify work?

Tags: audio, algorithms, dsp-core, voice, pitch

Does anyone know how does the **"Songify"** app algorithm work?

There are 2 inputs:

- speech (or amateur singing), and
- underlying music.

Somehow the speech is altered and mixed into the music. Which DSP algorithms are needed to achieve this effect?

- Pitch-shifter?
- Time-stretcher?
- Fundamental (F0) frequency detection?
- Auto-tune?
- Else?

What would be the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Melodify SDK](http://www.littleendian.com/developers/), does the same thing.

Comment: Can you please expand a little on what the linked-to page says?  Generally link-only answers on StackExchange are not very highly regarded.

Answer (score 2):

Songify seems use Prosodic Modification (Pitch, Time) for monophonic signals:

- First you need get the pitch contour and pitch duration from musics you want to follow
  (use one pitch track for monophonic signal like YIN,
  AMDF, Auto-Correlation)
- Split your imput signal in voiced/unvoiced
- Apply Pitch Scale Modification in voiced parts to match your extracted pitch contour (you can use PSOLA technique here)
- Apply Time stretch to match your extracted pitch duration (you can use PSOLA technique here)